# Using dict values as xticks in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, label

I created a line graph with 5 different time points, each time point contains 6 different values. In order to avoid overlapping error bars, I created an offset for each value in each time point and then added the offset.

Right now the time points have floats as names (1-5), but **I want the time points to have labels such as "before", "after1", "after2"**,...

I tried to assign a dictionary that contains the original float as a key and the string as a value (e.g. {'before': 1}.

I am stuck at how to include the dictionary values as xticks. Already tried the set_xticks(name_dict), but that does not work. Xlabel is used for the overall axis name. Is map an option here? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: can you show us the code?

Comment: `ax.set_xticklabels` allows you to set the texts displayed on the x ticks.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose your dictionary looks like this:

```
name_dict = {'before': 1, 'after1': 2, 'after2': 3, 'after3': 3, 'after4': 4}
```

First, you need to sue [`set_xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html) to specify the locations of x ticks

```
ax.set_xticks(name_dict.values())
```

Second, use [`set_xticklabels`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html) to show the labels at those locations

```
ax.set_xticklabels(name_dict.keys())
```

Answer (score 1):

As of matplotlib 3.8, `ax.set_xticks()` expects a list-like, and `ax.set_xticks(dic.keys())` throws:
`ValueError: 'locs' must be 1D with shape (N,), but your input has shape ()`.

The updated solution is

```
dic= {'before': 1, 'after1': 2, 'after2': 3, 'after3': 3, 'after4': 4}
ax.set_xticks(list(dic.values()))
ax.set_xticklabels(dic.keys())
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values are in the same order in the dictionary, you can use `set_xticks(name_dict.values)`. You can reorder them with a simple `for` loop if they are in the wrong order.

Comment: `name_dict.values` is a function, not a list.